# Pre-existing database with new rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I have an pre-existing database named `exam_prep` in `postgresql`, which i am using in `flask`.

I have created a new Rails application and i want to use that database with it.

So far I have run `rake db:structure:dump`, which created a `structure.sql` under the `db` folder.

After that I ran `db:structure:load`, but got the following error:

```
psql:/Users/namangupta/Desktop/app/db/structure.sql:49: ERROR:  type "batch_types_enum" already exists
rake aborted!
failed to execute:
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -q -f /Users/namangupta/Desktop/app/db/structure.sql exam_prep

Please check the output above for any errors and make sure that `psql` is installed in your PATH and has proper permissions.

/Users/namangupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:108:in `run_cmd'
/Users/namangupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:80:in `structure_load'
/Users/namangupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:223:in `structure_load'
/Users/namangupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:236:in `load_schema'
/Users/namangupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:255:in `block in load_schema_current'
/Users/namangupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:304:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/Users/namangupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:303:in `each'
/Users/namangupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:303:in `each_current_configuration'
/Users/namangupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:254:in `load_schema_current'
/Users/namangupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:290:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/namangupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/namangupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/namangupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:structure:load
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I want Rails to use the database and make a models within this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `db:structure:load` rake task creates a tables and columns from the `structure.sql` or `schema.rb`. You shouldn't need to run it, as your existing database already has all the tables you need.

Your next step would be to go about creating your model files and pointing them at the appropriate tables.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How can i create model that would point to the tables. I created a model simply by running the command `rails g model model_name` but when i opened the rails console and try to access the table entries i got nothing!

Comment: Have you pointed to the original database in config/database.yml?